# complex vs modular representation theory

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and consider the representation theory of $G$ over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbf{F}_p}$ of a finite field with $p$ elements, where $p$ is coprime to $|G|$. It is classical that in this situation, the representation theory of $G$ is "for all intents and purposes" equivalent to that over the complex field $\mathbf{C}$. I am wondering if there is a precise form of this statement. To be concrete, is there an equivalence between the category of finite dimensional representations of $G$ over $\overline{\mathbf{F}_p}$ and over $\mathbf{C}$ that respects irreducibility and direct sums? How are the characters related?

Comment: I cannot give a sleek description, but I guess one way of building it goes via a choice of splitting field $K$ of $\mathbf{Q}[G]$ that is also a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}$. For example a suitable cyclotomic extension will do. Then the assumption implies that $p$th roots of unity won't be needed. Next we need a suitable order within $K[G]$. That way we get something that is a free abelian group of finite rank, and can reduce mod $p$ etc. Many "non-canonical" steps (choices), so ... :-(

Comment: We can lift to characteristic zero more canonically by lifting representations to the ring of Witt vectors $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$.  Of course then you can embed $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, but that is non-canonical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there cannot be such an equivalence, because the category of finite-dimensional representations of $G$ over a field $K$ is sensitive to $K$: the endomorphism ring of every irreducible representation is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $K$, so in particular this category knows the characteristic of $K$, and if $K$ is algebraically closed then this category knows $K$ itself.

What I *believe* is true but have not carefully checked is, as Jyrki suggests in the comments, that there is some ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ in some number field $K$ (which can be chosen to be a cyclotomic field), admitting homomorphisms to both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that the corresponding extension of scalars functors $\text{Rep}_{\mathcal{O}_K}(G) \to \text{Rep}_{\mathbb{C}, \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}}(G)$

- are symmetric monoidal; this implies that they respect traces and characters in the sense that the trace / character over $\mathbb{C}, \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is the image of the trace / character over $\mathcal{O}_K$ with respect to the above homomorphisms,
- induce bijections on isomorphism classes of representations, and
- are additive and have the property that their hom spaces are the extensions of scalars of the hom spaces over $\mathcal{O}_K$.

**Edit:** This is not quite right; at a minimum we need to take $\text{Rep}_{\mathcal{O}_K}(G)$ to consist only of representations of $G$ on finite free $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules, and even then I'm not actually sure we get a bijection on isomorphism classes. Also we may need to take the localization $\mathcal{O}_K[|G|^{-1}]$ to be safe.

This is as close to an equivalence as I think you can get. I don't know a really slick proof of this; you need to show that every representation of $G$ is defined over the algebraic integers (actually it would be fine if we inverted $|G|$) which IIRC is a bit of a slog. The easiest special case of this occurs with the symmetric groups where it's classically known that all of their irreducible representations are defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ so you can take $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}$ here.

**Edit #2:** I've [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542726/what-can-be-said-about-splitting-rings-for-finite-groups) about this.

**Edit #3:** In the linked question you can find an argument which shows that there exists a finitely presented commutative ring $R_{\text{Iso}}$ with the property that

1. Every irreducible representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is defined over $R_{\text{Iso}}$, and
2. $R_{\text{Iso}}$ admits homomorphisms to $\mathbb{C}$ and to $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ for all primes $p \nmid |G|$ such that extension of scalars of the representations constructed above along these homomorphisms reproduces the irreducible representations of $G$ over these fields. In particular, the character of these representations can be computed over $R_{\text{Iso}}$ and maps to the character over $\mathbb{C}$ and over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

This is pretty close to satisfying. I think it is furthermore true that the category of representations of $G$ on finite free $R_{\text{Iso}}$-modules is close to equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ in the above sense but I haven't checked this carefully.

Comment: Note that none of this implies that one can canonically match up irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C}$ and over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. There is an unavoidable Galois symmetry ambiguity, which is a little hidden in the above but comes from the fact that the various choices of maps to $\mathbb{C}$ and to $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ are not unique. The best one can do is match up Galois orbits of representations. You can already see this for the cyclic groups.